# Why this jquery scrollbar plugin is not working on my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The link for the plugin:

```
http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/jquery-plugin/jscrollbar
```

As they said i just downloaded the files uploaded them to my website.
Then i embeded html and added this code:

```
<!-- include CSS & JS files -->
<!-- CSS file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/jScrollbar.jquery.css" media="screen" />
<!-- jQuery files -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/jquery-mousewheel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/jScrollbar.jquery.js"></script>
<!-- Main container -->
<div class="jScrollbar">
    <!-- Scrolling content container -->
    <div class="jScrollbar_mask">
        <p>
        <!-- Your long content here -->
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi...dfdfdsfdfddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
        </p>
    </div>
    <!-- slider container -->
    <div class="jScrollbar_draggable">
        <!-- slider -->
        <a href="#" class="draggable"></a>
    </div>
    <!-- don't forget to clear the floats -->
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    // simple jScrollbar plugin call
    $('.jScrollbar').jScrollbar();
    // more complex jScrollbar plugin call
    $('.jScrollbar').jScrollbar({
        scrollStep : 25,
        position : 'left',
        showOnHover : true
    });
});
</script>
```

But all i see is the text:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi...dfdfdsfdfddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

I didn't see any scrollbar/s
The links to the files are ok like i'm using with other jquery plugin that work.

Comment: Well, the URLs in your code get a 404 error so they don't exist. Check your file paths, and think about using relative paths, not absolute.

Comment: There is another question: Why do you use **this** scrollbar? Try another one - there are lots of scrollbar plugins that are better than this one. This one can't even scroll content without scrolling document on demo page, plus it additionally uses jQuery UI.

Comment: Try this plugin, its very good. http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/